# How to import leaflet-control-geocoder in Angular 12.x?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I've installed leaflet in angular 12 using the following commands:

```
npm install leaflet
npm install @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet
```

I included the styles: `./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css` on the `angular.json` file and the `LeafletModule` no my `app.module.ts`.

The map works fine, however, I'm trying to add the search input control from geocoder, for that I've included the link and script for geocoder links to my index.html, found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-control-geocoder).

And this is my ts file:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'leaf-let';

  private map: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.initMap();
  }

  private initMap(): void {
   this.map = L.map('map').setView([14.094167, -87.206667], 15);

   const tiles = L.tileLayer(
   'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
   {
     maxZoom: 19,
     attribution:'&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> ` 
       `contributors',
   }
 );

 tiles.addTo(this.map);

  //L.Control.geocoder().addTo(this.map);
 }
```

But when I do `L.Control.geocoder().addTo(this.map);` it gives me the error:

> property 'geocoder' does not exist on type 'typeof control'

Comment: You have the leaflet-control-geocoder imported as an script on index.html? 
Try at imports level, declare var Control;

Then inside yout component Control.geocoder().addTo(this.map);

Answer (score 2):

You have not **imported** the library and its style:

1. Install leaflet-control-geocoder
2. `import "leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css";`
3. `import "leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js";`

Also it seems you are not using ngx-leaflet but vanilla leaflet instead. If that is the case you should go with the following approach:

```
private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([14.094167, -87.206667], 15);

    const tiles = L.tileLayer(
      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }
    ).addTo(this.map);

    tiles.addTo(this.map);

    (L.Control as any).geocoder().addTo(this.map);
}
```

Initialize the plugin using `(L.Control as any)` to avoid getting the typescript error but the error you were getting was because you did not import the library in advance.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-12x-with-leaflet-control-geocoder-1c2zn)